# Clutch problems

Tags: clutch, clutch-cylinder, flywheel, master-cylinder, seat-leon

I have a Seat Leon 1.9TDI with about 53k miles on it.

While driving one day I started noticing that when I press the clutch pedal down and then release it, it starts to get stuck on the way back up. I went to the mechanic and he said that the clutch and flywheel need replacement which costs no less than £500 (I don't want to spend this much on one person's recommendation).

I continued driving as it is a necessity and wasn't occurring much, the problem slowly just started to go away and I'd notice it happening very rarely (usually long drives). It has started up again but this time when I press it, it doesn't come back up instantly like it was. I have to tap it with my foot to release it, and even sometimes pull it back up; however when I pull it back up and go to press it again; it feels extremely stiff and doesn't engage until I press it a few times forcefully (as in traffic I don't want to look like an idiot). The transmission is working completely fine.

I read online that people with this issue usually have a bad master or slave cylinder. What do you guys think it could be?

There is also this I came across but I'm not sure what this component is and what the cost of getting it fixed would be: http://www.schaeffler.com/remotemedien/media/_shared_media/08_media_library/01_publications/automotiveaftermarket/serviceinfo/downloads_9/luk_3/si_luk_0024_de_en.pdf

Comment: I think the FIRST thing I would do is inspect the clutch master and slave cylinders. If the piston in either is getting stuck , or the flexible hose is bad, it will cause the same symptoms. Other than not coming back up quickly, does the clutch engage normally otherwise? Inspecting the cylinders is as simple as disconnecting the slave at the transmission and moving the pedal up and down and seeing if it's still smooth. It's less than a 1 hour job and may save you 80% of the cost of putting in a new clutch.

Answer (score 2):

By what you describe its highly unlikely that the clutch is at fault here.. To me too it sounds like either the clutch master cylinder is sticking or the clutch pedal mechanism is at fault.. Or perhaps the clutch hydraulic system just needs bleeding. A repair to anything mentioned shouldn't be too expensive.

The component you linked to could possibly also be at fault here.. This unit just smooths out any transmitted pulses which can sometimes be transferred through a clutches hydraulic mechanism.